# setting up a webkit on an iframe before load

Tags: html, ios, reactjs, iframe, wkwebview

I am trying to mimic what wkwebview does on iOS to an iframe on a webclient.

Essentially what happens is before the iframe is loaded it injects a function the iOS client can read.

on the page loaded within the iframe it calls a function to communicate with the iOS client.

```
if (window.webkit) {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.interOp.postMessage(chatMsg);
} else if (window.parent) {
    window.parent.postMessage(chatMsg, '*');
}
```

I don't want it to fall into the else window.parent block since postMessage gets quite a bit of traffic from extensions and other applications.

I'd like to add to the Iframe's window object the same `webkit.messageHandlers.interOp.postMessage` function and listen on that level.

The Iframe domain and the WebClient domain are different.

Another approach would be to only listen to calls to postMessage called by the Iframe. Any ideas are welcome thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a same-domain iframe, then you simply assign a function to the window of the parent, as in:

`` window.iframeMessageReceiver = msg => alert(`Message received from iframe: ${msg}`) ``

And you call this function inside of your iframe's if block:

`parent.iframeMessageReceiver(chatMsg)`

Comment: This implementation will not work on the iOS client or Android client. It is also different domain's.